# How can I check if a value already exists in a hash?

Tags: ruby

Is there any method to check if hash contains a particular value? I've tried like this:

```
words = {}
puts "Which word do you want to learn to Baby?"
wordsvariable = gets.chomp
if action == "1" && words.include?(wordsvariable)
  puts "This word is already learned by the Baby, try again."
elsif action == "1" && !words.include?(wordsvariable)
words[Time.now] = wordsvariable
  puts "Congrats you have learn word: #{wordsvariable} to Baby."
end
```

If the word is already learned by the baby (i.e., the word is in the hash already), I don't want to allow the baby to learn it. Otherwise, I let the baby learn it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: How're you storing the words in the `words` hash?

Comment: I forgot it when i translate my code. @SebastianPalma

Comment: why your key is time and not the word?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev because the program request time too thats why.

Comment: @Dion12345: no, your hash. Why is it `time => word` and not `word => time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if there is a key with a given value, you can use the `key` method on the hash:

```
words.key(wordsvariable)
```

If that returns a value, `wordsvariable` is in the hash.

---

You are storing the words in a hash with the time as a key like this:

```
{
  2018-04-05 01:15:32 +0200=>"foo", 
  2018-04-05 01:15:32 +0200=>"bar"
}
```

A more natural way of storing the words and time might be to have the key and value opposite of how you have it now.

Instead of using: `words[Time.now] = wordsvariable`, you can use `words[wordsvariable] = Time.now`

And then use:

```
words[wordsvariable]
```

to test if there is a value there.